# possible to use array_map with vprintf?

Tags: php

Is it possible to use array_map('vprintf', ....)?

If yes, what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide an array of arrays (the first dimension describing the array of arguments for all elements of $arr, the second describing the values for one format string) as third argument:

```
<?php

$arr = array("test %s\n", "test2 %s\n");
array_map('vprintf', $arr, array(array('val1'), array('val2')));
```

Output:

```
test val1
test2 val2
```